# Creating different delays for animations on first and second click + chaining delays

Tags: javascript

My title is not very explanatory due to lack of space so I will be more specific. I often have ideas which require either a concept like the first or second section of code. I will come to the point. I feel the use of  setTimeout for those two scenarios are not appropriate. It creates a huge overlapping mess without clearTimeout and just doesnt seem right. This is where I ask the community: what alternative is there to what I am trying to achieve? Apart from settimout and setinterval, is there any alternative, more efficient way of doings things when doing complex chaining for animations or when registering multiple clicks like in the example below?

Here an example with clicks:

```
document.getElementById("example").addEventListener("click", function(){

    clicked = false;

    if (clicked = false){
    clearTimeout(t2);
    var t1 = setTimeout(function(){
        // animate 1
    }, 1000);
    }

    else {
    clearTimeout(t1);
    var t2 = setTimeout(function(){
        // animate 1
    }, 2000);
    }

    clicked = !clicked

};
```

or there is the question of  chaining stuff:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    // does stuff
       setTimeout(function(){
            // does stuff
              setTimeout(function(){
                     // does stuff
              }, 1000);
        }, 1000);
}, 3000);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would look into triggering a custom event when the animation completes, and that is how you accomplish your animation chaining.  Create a listener for the custom event that triggers the next animation in the chain.  This is something that is already build into the new [Web Animations](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2014/05/Web-Animations---element-animate-is-now-in-Chrome-36) standard.  There's also a javascript [shim available](https://github.com/web-animations/web-animations-js) for the API if you want backwards compatibility with non-supporting browsers.